# Мне нужно добавить отсутствующие ключи в список словарей из списка с уникальными ключами

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, list, словари

Мне нужно добавить отсутствующие ключи в список словарей из списка с уникальными ключами
и если ключ из списка уже есть в словаре тогда пропустить его
вот код в котором должно это работать

```
import jsonlines
import datetime
import itertools

with jsonlines.open('data.jsonl', 'r') as jsonl_f:
    lst = list(jsonl_f)

lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x['time_created'], reverse=False)

answ_list = []
temp = ''

for my_dict in lst:
    if temp != my_dict['name']:
        if temp != my_dict['time_created']:
            answ_list.append(my_dict)
            temp = my_dict['name']

for value in lst:
    value['time_created'] = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(value['time_created'])

res = list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sub.keys() for sub in lst)))
for value in answ_list:
    for i in res:
        if i not in value:
            if i == 'gender':
                value['gender'] = 'woman'
            if i == 'last_name':
                value['last_name'] = 'George'
            if i == 'age':
                value['age'] = 21
            if i == 'city':
                value['city'] = 'Seul'
            if i == 'premium':
                value['premium'] = None
            if i == 'ip':
                value['ip'] = '111.11.11.1'
            if i == 'birth_day':
                value['birth_day'] = '1992.02.01'
            if i == 'balance':
                value['balance'] = '1000'
```

я пробовал написать код для это через for loop

```
for value in answ_list:
    for i in res:
        if i not in value:
            if i == 'gender':
                value['gender'] = 'woman'
            if i == 'last_name':
                value['last_name'] = 'George'
            if i == 'age':
                value['age'] = 21
            if i == 'city':
                value['city'] = 'Seul'
            if i == 'premium':
                value['premium'] = None
            if i == 'ip':
                value['ip'] = '111.11.11.1'
            if i == 'birth_day':
                value['birth_day'] = '1992.02.01'
            if i == 'balance':
                value['balance'] = '1000'
```

но к сожалению не работает подскажите как можно исправить этот код

вот как выглядит список словарей

> {"name": "Thomas", "time_created": 1665070563, "gender": null} {"name": "Lisa", "time_created": 1665226717, "gender": "female", "age": 59} {"name": "James", "time_created": 1664913997, "gender": "male", "last_name": "Rogers"} {"name": "Helen", "time_created": 1664651357, "gender": "female", "last_name": "Scott", "ip": "111.111.11.1"}

а должен как то так

> {"name": "Thomas", "time_created": 1665070563, "gender": null, age: 21, birth_day: '1996.01.01' balance: 110, premium: Null, ip:'1111.11.11.1'} {"name": "Lisa", "time_created": 1665226717, "gender": "female", "age": 59, birth_day: '1996.01.01' balance: 110, premium: Null, ip: '1111.11.11.1'} и так далее....

вот сам список уникальних ключей

> ['age', 'last_name', 'birth_day', 'balance', 'name', 'premium', 'ip', 'city', 'gender', 'time_created']

Comment: непонятно, почему всем добавляются такие странные данные, особенно порадовал день рождения. Если они неизвестны, то лучше об этом знать. Ну, а так, если d - словарь, `d[x] = d.get(x, default_value_for x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать вот такой код для пополнения некоторого словаря стандартными значениями для некоторых обязательных ключей:

```
defaults = {
    'age': 21,
    'last_name': 'George',
    'birth_day': '1992.02.01',
    'balance': '1000'
}

object = {
    'age': 32,
    'data': [1, 2, 3]
}

for key, value in defaults.items():
    object[key] = object.get(key, value)

print(object)
```

в результате был:

```
{'age': 32, 'data': [1, 2, 3]}
```

а стал:

```
{'age': 32, 'data': [1, 2, 3], 'last_name': 'George', 'birth_day': '1992.02.01', 'balance': '1000'}
```